# Assembly loop through a string to count characters

Tags: c, string, gcc, assembly, intel-syntax

i try to make an assembly code that count how many characters is in the string, but i get an error.

Code, I use gcc and intel_syntax

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char *s = "aqr  b qabxx xryc pqr";
int x;

asm volatile (
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "mov eax, %1;"
    "xor ebx,ebx;"
    "loop:"
        "mov al,[eax];"
        "or al, al;"
        "jz print;"
        "inc ebx;"
        "jmp loop"
    "print:"
    "mov %0, ebx;"
    ".att_syntax prefix;"
    : "=r" (x)
    : "r" (s)
    : "eax", "ebx"
);

    printf("Length of string: %d\n", x);
    return 0;

}
```

And i got error:

```
Error: invalid use of register
```

Finally I want to make program, which search for regex pattern([pq][^a]+a) and prints it's start position and length. I wrote it in C, but I have to make it work in assembly:
My C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char *s = "aqr  b qabxx xryc pqr";
  int y,i;
  int x=-1,length=0, pos = 0;

    int len = strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<len;i++){
        if((s[i] == 'p' || s[i] == 'q') && length<=0){
            pos = i;
            length++;
            continue;
        } else if((s[i] != 'a')) && pos>0){
            length++;
        } else if((s[i] == 'a') && pos>0){
            length++;
            if(y < length) {
                y=length;
                length = 0;
                x = pos;
                pos = 0;    
            }
            else 
                length = 0;
                pos = 0;
        }
    }  

    printf("position: %d, length: %d", x, y);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Is there a line number for the error?

Comment: You shouldn't switch the assembler syntax behind the compiler's back or else it will do the substitutions wrong . Use `-masm=intel` compiler switch if you want intel syntax.

Comment: 7 line, where it starts assembly block

Comment: @Jester This is directive from my professor and I only can write code between "mov eax, %1" and "print:"

Comment: Your professor is incompetent then. You are also missing a semicolon after `jmp loop`.

Comment: As for the second half of your post (the regex stuff), this is an entirely separate question.  You might take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/40717389/2189500 (are you guys in the same class?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the semicolon after `jmp loop` and `print:`.

---

Also your asm isn't going to work correctly.  You move the pointer to `s` into eax, but then you overwrite it with `mov al,[eax]`.  So the next pass thru the loop, eax doesn't point to the string anymore.

And when you fix that, you need to think about the fact that each pass thru the loop needs to change eax to point to the next character, otherwise `mov al,[eax]` keeps reading the same character.

---

Since you haven't accepted an answer yet (by clicking the checkmark to the left), there's still time for one more edit.

Normally I don't "do people's homework", but it's been a few days.  Presumably the due date for the assignment has passed.  Such being the case, here are a few solutions, both for the education of the OP and for future SO users:

1) Following the (somewhat odd) limitations of the assignment:

```
asm volatile (
    ".intel_syntax noprefix;"
    "mov eax, %1;"
    "xor ebx,ebx;"
    "cmp byte ptr[eax], 0;"
    "jz print;"
    "loop:"
        "inc ebx;"
        "inc eax;"
        "cmp byte ptr[eax], 0;"
        "jnz loop;"
    "print:"
    "mov %0, ebx;"
    ".att_syntax prefix;"
    : "=r" (x)
    : "r" (s)
    : "eax", "ebx"
);
```

2) Violating some of the assignment rules to make slightly better code:

```
asm (
    "\n.intel_syntax noprefix\n\t"
    "mov eax, %1\n\t"
    "xor %0,%0\n\t"
    "cmp byte ptr[eax], 0\n\t"
    "jz print\n"
    "loop:\n\t"
        "inc %0\n\t"
        "inc eax\n\t"
        "cmp byte ptr[eax], 0\n\t"
        "jnz loop\n"
    "print:\n"
    ".att_syntax prefix"
    : "=r" (x)
    : "r" (s)
    : "eax", "cc", "memory"
);
```

This uses 1 fewer register (no `ebx`) and omits the (unnecessary) `volatile` qualifier.  It also adds the "cc" clobber to indicate that the code modifies the flags, and uses the "memory" clobber to ensure that any 'pending' writes to `s` get flushed to memory before executing the asm.  It also uses formatting (\n\t) so the output from building with `-S` is readable.

3) Advanced version which uses even fewer registers (no `eax`), checks to ensure that `s` is not NULL (returns -1), uses symbolic names and assumes `-masm=intel` which results in more readable code:

```
__asm__ (
    "test %[string], %[string]\n\t"
    "jz print\n"
    "loop:\n\t"
        "inc %[length]\n\t"
        "cmp byte ptr[%[string] + %[length]], 0\n\t"
        "jnz loop\n"
    "print:"
    : [length] "=r" (x)
    : [string] "r" (s), "[length]" (-1)
    : "cc", "memory"
);
```

Getting rid of the (arbitrary and not well thought out) assignment constraints allows us to reduce this to 7 lines (5 if we don't check for NULL, 3 if we don't count labels [which aren't actually instructions]).

There are ways to improve this even further (using `%=` on the labels to avoid possible duplicate symbol issues, using local labels (`.L`), even writing it so it works for *both* `-masm=intel` and `-masm=att`, etc.), but I daresay that any of these 3 are better than the code in the original question.

---

Well Kuba, I'm not sure what more you are after here before you'll accept an answer.  Still, it does give me the chance to include Peter's version.

4) Pointer increment:

```
__asm__ (
    "cmp byte ptr[%[string]], 0\n\t"
    "jz .Lprint%=\n"
    ".Loop%=:\n\t"
    "inc %[length]\n\t"
    "cmp byte ptr[%[length]], 0\n\t"
    "jnz .Loop%=\n"
    ".Lprint%=:\n\t"    
    "sub %[length], %[string]"
    : [length] "=&r" (x)
    : [string] "r" (s), "[length]" (s)
    : "cc", "memory"
);
```

This does not do the 'NULL pointer' check from #3, but it does do the 'pointer increment' that Peter was recommending.  It also avoids potential duplicate symbols (using `%=`), and uses 'local' labels (ones that start with `.L`) to avoid extra symbols getting written to the object file.

From a "performance" point of view, this might be slightly better (I haven't timed it).  However from a "school project" point of view, the clarity of #3 seems like it would be a better choice.  From a "what would I write in the real world if for some bizarre reason I HAD to write this in asm instead of just using a standard c function" point of view, I'd probably look at usage, and unless this was performance critical, I'd be tempted to go with #3 in order to ease future maintenance.

Comment: I'd actually prefer the pointer-increment version (not all Intel CPUs can micro-fuse an indexed addressing mode), but instead of incrementing a counter in the loop, just do `len = end - start` once you find the end.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I tried writing this in c to find out which gcc would generate.  Presumably that would be the "best."  Unfortunately it generates both, depending on exactly how the c code is written.

Comment: As long as the loop is less than 3 ALU uops, it doesn't matter much either way.  The frontend shouldn't be a bottleneck, so optimizing for micro-fusion is irrelevant.  (And don't assume that gcc knows this.  It's not perfect, and I don't think its weights for the costs of different addressing modes are much of a model, esp. since it doesn't behave much differently in that respect with `-mtune=nehalem` vs. `-mtune=sandybridge` vs. `-mtune=skylake` (SKL can once again micro-fuse indexed addressing modes inside the OOO core, not just in the decoders / uop cache)

Comment: While I don't consider gcc to be definitive wrt optimal perf, it is a credible way for those of us who aren't ready to read Agner Fog's work to form an initial opinion.  My expectation is that most of the "big" wins tend to be there.  You just need to be ready to reconsider if real world timing shows otherwise.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely a good approach.  gcc generally avoids hitting any serious stalls, although it will sometimes cause partial-register stalls that could easily have been avoided, even with `-mtune=core2`. :/