# Very simple compare function not working

Tags: assembly, arm

I've just started learning assembly in one of my classes and am having trouble writing a program that takes two arrays and compares each element, then stores the larger value back into the first array.

Here is my code with excruciatingly elementary comments (note that this is being ran on an arduino, hence the asm pseudo-function):

```
void sort1 (char *A, char *B, int N) {
  asm(
    "mov a1, %[A];"           // Move address A into a1 
    "mov a2, %[B];"           // Move address B into a2
    "mov a3, %[N];"           // Move array size N into a3

    "mov r1, #0;"  // r1 = 0
    "L1: cmp r1, a3;" // compare r1 and N
         "it ge;"
         "bge end;"  // if r1 >= N, jump to end (end condition of for loop is met)
       "ldrb v1,[a1];" // load a1 into v1
       "ldrb v2,[a2];" // load a2 into v2
       "cmp v1, v2;" // compare v1 and v2
         "it lt;" // if v1 is less than v2
         "strblt v2,[a1];" // store v2 in a1
       "add a1, #1;" // go to next element in array A
       "add a2, #1;" // go to next element in array B
       "add r1, #1;" // r1 = r1 + 1, equivalent to "i++"
       "b L1;" // branch to beginning of loop
    "end:"

    : : [A]"r"(A), [B]"r"(B), [N]"r"(N)  // Substitute C++ variables
    : "a1", "a2", "a3", "r1", "v1", "v2" // Place any registers used here to not clobber
  );  
}
```

Currently my program is giving back the same arrays A and B regardless of a value in B being greater than the one in A.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry this is such a simple question that probably has a very simple solution, but most of this has been self-learning and I'm struggling figuring out where the problem is.

Comment: You're missing a `"memory"` clobber to let the compiler know you write (and read) memory that isn't an input operand.  IDK if that matters.  I'd highly recommend writing the whole function in pure asm (in a `.S` file), not inline-asm in C.  That's the hardest way to learn asm.

Comment: Did you try single-stepping through it in a debugger?  If the compiler isn't doing what you expect, you will have a good chance of noticing when you single-step out of your code and into the compiler-generated code.

Comment: @PeterCordes That didn't seem to help, no. And I would do that, but we're writing multiple functions in a .ino file to interact with the arduino's serial monitor, so we're kind of forced to do it this way unfortunately. -- We also haven't really gone over debugging in too much detail with the Arduino IDE so I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: For more about inline-asm being the hardest way to learn asm, see [the 2nd half of David Wohlferd's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40735790/224132).  You have to already understand asm, and understand how compilers work, to correctly describe the interface between your code and C to the compiler.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand why compiling a `.c` with this mostly-inline-asm function is any different for you from compiling a `.S` with a pure-asm implementation.  But anyway, you absolutely need to be using a debugger.  Without being able to single-step through your code and see register values change, you're wasting your own and everyone else's time.  It will be worth the time it takes to figure out how to use the debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know how to debug when using bash, but as far as I can tell the Arduino IDE doesn't have a debugger. I press "Upload" and it compiles and writes the program to the Due's flash. I don't know how to compile this .ino file in bash either, this class is kind of separate from my other computer science ones and isn't as focused on the actual programming aspect, so many things remain uncovered.

Comment: I don't know much about ARM, but isn't a2 just an alternate name for r1 (per [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/ch06s02s01.html))?  If so, trying to use both seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd Oh gosh, duh. I was working with some pseudo-code I had written earlier and totally forgot to change that name. Thank you so much, that fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining all the comments into an answer:

I don't know much about ARM, but isn't `a2` just an alternate name for `r1` (per [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/ch06s02s01.html))? If so, trying to use both like this seems like a bad idea.

And as Peter mentioned, I might use a "memory" clobber here as well as "cc".

Also, it appears that `mov a3, %[N]` is unnecessary.  It looks like you can just use %[N] (which is already a register) and save yourself a register.

And finally, my standard comments about why you shouldn't use gcc's inline asm is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).

Comment: Oh yes, good point about needing a `"cc"` clobber.  Easy to forget since it's implicit on x86.